# Software to Measure the Size of a Software Project

Tags: software-development, file-management, source-code

I wonder if there is software that would assist in estimating the "size" of a project. There are of course many ways to do this, and many things to measure(a few including):

- Lines of Code
- Number of Files
- Number of Folders
- Number of Interdependence's
- Unit Tests

And many more, some [detailed here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_sizing).

Comment: Which operating system and which price?

Comment: Windows, open source preferably, but I'm open to anything really.

Comment: Can I suggest changing the title & text from Estimate to Measure as it sounds like you have the code and need to summarise how big it is rather than you are planning a project and need to Estimate the size it will be.

Comment: Which programming languages is the project written in?

Comment: Excellent suggestion, I changed the title to Measure. Actually what I'm trying to get at is the growth(size KB, tests, files, etc..)  in my application over time(version to version, or build to build). It's mostly C#, but I occasionally develop in other languages so I wonder if there is an application that will do it generically?

Comment: If this doesn't exist maybe I'll code something up in WPF, maybe this will be useful for someone else too...